# Comments formatting

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I can't get the formatting to work in comments I have added ...

Here is an example:
[Advice on most conventional method of parsing data from an input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251390/advice-on-most-conventional-method-of-parsing-data-from-an-input-file/15251613#comment21511154_15251613)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add a link to your comment you can do it like this

```
[link text](http://link.com)
```

Comment: If you click the "Help" link next to the comment field, then click "Learn more", you'll get taken [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) with lots of useful formatting tips.

Comment: Now it works on the Meta site, will try it on StackOverflow...

[Learn more](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @Philip Make sure there are no spaces between ] and (, and that your link starts with an http://

Comment: here is the link I was trying: [Much ADO About Text Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx)

Comment: add `http://` to it

Comment: See Raghav's comment

Comment: AH I got it, thanks guys !

Comment: [it works with multiple words too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170464/172011)

Answer (score 2):

HTML tags in comments and chat don't work, you have to use markdown.

For a full list of the available markdown see [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Common formatting used in comments:

Links:

```
[link title](link URL)
```

Italics:

```
*Text in asterisks* or _text here_
```

Bold:

```
**double asterisks** or __double (lines?)__
```

For code you use backtics (`).